# writing a custom get method for a scala map

Tags: scala, design-patterns

I have a map which is something like

```
val m = Map("foo" -> "bar", "faz" -> "baz")
```

I need to write a custom `get` method, so that the key can be the key in the map with a number in the end.

So for example:

```
m.get("foo1") should return "bar"
```

I am looking for a good scala pattern to solve this problem.

Also I am generating the above map from a for loop using yield, so I can't do something like this

```
val m = CustomMap("foo" -> "bar")
```

Any solutions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can generate a map from a `for` comprehension, and *then* convert it to `CustomMap`. You just need to define a
`def apply(map: Map[String, String]) = CustomMap(map.toSeq :_*)` in `CustomMap` - then you can do `val m = CustomMap( for { ... } yield ... )`

Secondly, if it doesn't have to be  named `get` (it probably shouldn't be anyway), you can do this sort of thing with an implicit:

```
 object PimpMyMap { 
    val pref = ".*?(\\d+)".r
    implicit class Pimped[V](val map: Map[String,V]) extends AnyVal {
      def getPrefix(key: String): Option[V] = map.get(key).orElse { key match {
          case pref(k) => map.get(k)
          case _ => None
  }
 }
```

Now you can write things like:

```
  import PimpMyMap._
  val map = Map("foo" -> 1)
  val one = map.getPrefix("foo123") // Some(1)
  val anotherOne = map.getPrefix("foo") // also Some(1);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes initially I added a custom `getXXX` method, but for my use-case, I want the clients to use only the custom getXXX and not the default `get`.

Comment: I got it that you don't want it ... What I am saying is, that it is most probably wrong to want it :). You can still override if you want though, I am no sure what's the problem with that

Comment: No there is no problem. I was just explaining my use-case. I got your solution with the `CustomMap` and I think that should work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an `implicit class` and `implicit conversion`:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object MapHelpers {
  implicit def optionStringToString(maybeS: Option[String]): String = maybeS.getOrElse("")
  implicit class MapWithIntKey(val m: Map[String, String]) extends Map[String, String] {
    override def get(key: String): Option[String] = {
      val intRegex = """(\d+)""".r
      val keyWithoutInt = intRegex
        .findFirstMatchIn(key)
        .map(int => {
          val idx = key.indexOf(int.toString)
          key.slice(0, idx)
        })
        .getOrElse(key)
      m.get(keyWithoutInt)
    }

    def +[V1 >: String](
        kv: (String, V1)): scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, V1] = m + kv
    def -(key: String): scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, String] = m - key
    def iterator: Iterator[(String, String)] = m.iterator
  }
}

object App {

  import MapHelpers._

  def testMapImplicit(): Unit = {
    val myMap: MapWithIntKey = Map("foo" -> "bar", "faz" -> "baz")
    val result: String = myMap.get("foo1")
    println("result", result) // bar
  }
}
```

[Working Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/adrice727/ZXAzuKNaSamCzB74F0yxEQ)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sure way to get the real key from the fake key, you can do this with `Map.withDefault`:

```
class CustomMap[K, +V] private (underlying: Map[K, Option[V]]) {
  def get(k: K): Option[V] = underlying(k)
}

object CustomMap {
  def apply[K, V](original: Map[K, V], keyReducer: K => K) = new CustomMap(originalMap.
    mapValues(Some(_)).
    withDefault(k => originalMap.get(keyReducer(k))
  )
}
```

In your case, you can use this with

```
val stringKeyReducer: String => String = k.reverse.dropWhile(_.isDigit).reverse
```

to drop the digits at the end of your strings, so

```
CustomMap(Map("foo" -> "bar"), stringKeyReducer).get("foo1") = Some("bar")
```

Comment: this one is interesting and simpler solution as well,

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution which combines both the answers.

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object MapHelpers {
  implicit def optionStringToString(maybeS: Option[String]): String = maybeS.getOrElse("")
  implicit class MapWithIntKey(val m: Map[String, String]) extends Map[String, String] {
    override def get(key: String): Option[String] = {
      val prefix = "(.*?)\\d+".r
      m.get(key).orElse{
        key match {
          case prefix(p) => m.get(p)
          case _ => None
        }
      }
    }

    def +[V1 >: String](kv: (String, V1)): scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, V1] = m + kv
    def -(key: String): scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, String] = m - key
    def iterator: Iterator[(String, String)] = m.iterator
  }
}

object App {

  import MapHelpers._

  def testMapImplicit(): Unit = {
    val myMap: MapWithIntKey = Map("foo" -> "bar", "faz" -> "baz")
    println("result - number match ", myMap.get("foo1"))
    println("result - exact match  ", myMap.get("foo"))
  }

}

App.testMapImplicit()
```

[Working Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/VsjbmDLKTHC8zgurCENISQ)